# asp .net mvc change password issue firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, firefox, membership, change-password

//UPDATE : Described problem occurs only in Firefox Browser

I've written small app in mvc 2.0, which uses aspnetdb to manage users and standard Account controllers / views etc.

My problem is when i try to change password for user sometimes after typing old password and putting new password, another window opens where i can (?) choose user to change password.

It is very strange, it happens only to some users in application while for other it works quite fine.

Could anyone give me any suggestion what's going on ?

#### Update:

I don't know whats the difference at first I thought it depends on roles they have defined in application but then this pattern failed.
I don't use any js here

My controller actions looks like:

```
        [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        ViewData["PasswordLength"] = this.MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (this.MembershipService.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Błędne hasło aktualne lub nowe nie spełnia wymagań.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ViewData["PasswordLength"] = this.MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
        return View(model);
    }
```

And ChangePassword.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TheApp.Web.Models.ChangePasswordModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="changePasswordTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Change Password
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="changePasswordContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Change Password</h2>
    <p>
        Min password length: <%= Html.Encode(ViewData["PasswordLength"]) %>.
    </p>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Message.") %>
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword) %>
                    <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword) %>
                </div>
                
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword) %>
                </div>
                
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword) %>
                </div>
                
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Change Password" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

... and weird window with users list (which is incomplete btw) shows even before

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
```

invocation.

Comment: You need to add some more information and quite possibly some code snippets.  For example what is different between the users that experience this and those that don't? whats the action look like for change password? is there any javascript going on on the change password form?

Answer (score 0):

I've added in my view `autocomplete="off"` in all input fields and it helped :)